# Azure Logic App - Twitter Connector Issues

Tags: azure, logic, workflow

I have a Logic App with Twitter connector and a Dropbox connector. The latter has repeater, which loops over the Twitter body and upload a text file in each iteration with Tweet_ID as file name. The Dropbox connector many times returns conflict errors, it seems Tweet connector keeps returning same tweets again and again, which had been already processed, which results in duplicate file names.

When I look at the output of the Dropbox connector, below is the body it returns.

```
"body": {
                "status": 409,
                "source": "api-content.dropbox.com",
                 "message": "conflict_file"
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have probably seen this page https://azure.microsoft.com/sv-se/documentation/articles/app-service-logic-use-logic-app-features/ where they show how to do this.

Have you checked that you don't supply the same Tweet_ID several times? The logic app json format it a bit tricky right now, with not so much documentation.

/dag

Comment: That is actually the issue, Twitter connector returns the same Tweet_ID (tweet) multiple times even if that is processed previously and this happens for sometime and then it starts skipping the old tweets. The expected behavior is that Twitter connector should only return new tweets.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. The twitter connector doesn't "remember" the tweets that are returned from a search. It will return the same again. (Just to be clear. We are discussing the Twitter Connector Action Search Tweets.)